# How to identify that script is getting killed python

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a `VM` which runs a `python script` for long time and shuts down the VM once finished.During processing of that script it stores it's `logs in mongo db` on another machine. 
But also, there is an hourly cron on the same VM, which kills my script if it runs for more than 3 hours and terminates the VM forcefully.

I want to identify from same python script and log the time at which it is going to be killed.

**Note** - I don't have access to edit cron job. So need something from the script itself. I have only rights to edit my python script. VM automatically picks it up from github repository and runs it on that VM.

I tried this code bu no luck:

```
import atexit

def exit_handler():
    """ """
    print "Script exited" 
    vmapi = VMAPIMAnager() 
    vmapi.store_log(datetime.datetime.now())

atexit.register(exit_handler)
```

Comment: keep logging the time until your script is running. So last the time entry is when your script was closed forcefully?

Comment: @dnit13m :- That is already done. but sometimes If the processing is about to finish I have to run one more command to skip it's termination.

Comment: @dnit13 : Need answer or remove negative marking

Comment: I did not negate you. I am a victim myself :(